Podman; problems mapping a volume with www-data
I'm trying to map a directory in an offshoot of my home directory into a podman container,so it can be used by nginx, which needs their uid/gid to match www-data inside the container (uid=33). The directory tree has the permissions of my main user account.
Unfortunately when I try and run this command as my unprivileged user,
podman run --userns="keep-id:uid=33,gid=33" -p 8080:80 -d -v./dokuwiki:/var/www/dokuwiki  localhost/dokuwiki 

I get this error:
Error: crun: make `/home/james/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/dca7028e0bb13b13b2fcbe101e20b0ffdaa6467c8c62a0120b7f48f51dbc5d91/merged` private: Permission denied: OCI permission denied

The dockerfile is relatively simple;
FROM docker.io/debian:bookworm
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt  update -y &&  apt install -y nginx-full php8.2 php8.2-xml php8.2-fpm 
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/dokuwiki
COPY 000-default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN echo "exit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
CMD /etc/init.d/php8.2-fpm restart && /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"

Any ideas?
